# My code runs but its sloppy and I'm sure it has extra syntax. Any recommendations?

Tags: ruby

Here's a problem I'm trying to solve:

> Write a function `lucky_sevens?(numbers)`, which takes in an array of
>   integers and returns `true` if any three consecutive elements sum to `7`.
>
> ```
> lucky_sevens?([2,1,5,1,0]) == true # 1 + 5 + 1 == 7
> lucky_sevens?([0,-2,1,8]) == true # -2 + 1 + 8 == 7
> lucky_sevens?([7,7,7,7]) == false
> lucky_sevens?([3,4,3,4]) == false
> ```
>
> Make sure your code correctly checks for edge cases (i.e. the first
>   and last elements of the array).

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  i = 0
  while i < numbers.length - 2

    if numbers[i] + numbers[i + 1] + numbers[i + 2] == 7
        puts true
        return true
    end
    i+=1
    end 
    puts false
    return false
end
```

While my code does seem to work (I did some test cases), I know it can be improved. There's no reason to have both `puts` and `return` statements. I'm also wondering if there are general improvements to the syntax itself that can make it much more readable.

Comment: Since your code is working correctly, I think this question would be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using an index outside of a block, you can often improve it. Here is an orthodox way.

```
def lucky_sevens?(numbers)
  numbers.each_cons(3).any?{|x, y, z| x + y + z == 7}
end
```

Comment: Why not `numbers.each_cons(3).any? {|nums| nums.sum == 7 }`?

Comment: Because there is no `sum` method in Ruby?

Comment: Oops, forgot I was in the Rails console. Pretend I said `numbers.each_cons(3).any? {|nums| nums.reduce(:+) == 7 }`. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
def consecutive_sum?(arr, n, tot)
  return false if arr.size < n
  t = arr[0,n].reduce(:+)
  return true if t == tot
  (arr.size-n).times.any? { |i| (t+=(arr[i+n]-arr[i]))==tot }
end

consecutive_sum?([2,1,5,1,0], 3, 7) #=> true
consecutive_sum?([2,1,5,2,1], 3, 7) #=> false
```

3 numbers are summed to obtain `t`, then there are at most 2 adjustments to `t` that each involve an addition and a subtraction, so there are at most 7 additions/subtractions.  By contrast, @sawa's solution using `each_cons(3)` requires at most 3 summations of 3 numbers, for a total of nine additions. Regardless, I would expect `each_cons` to be be faster, and it certainly reads better.

I presented this answer merely to suggest an efficient way of summing runs for larger values of `n`. You did not ask for this, but you or some readers may find it useful in other situations. Suppose, for example:

```
consecutive_sum?([1,4,2,5,6,2,7,1,5,2,8,4,3,1,7,6,3,1],6,21) #=> true
```

6 numbers are summed to obtain `t`, then there are at most 12 adjustments to `t`, each involving an addition and a subtraction, a total of 30 additions/subtractions. `each_cons(6)`, however, requires 13 sums of 6 numbers each, or 78 additions.